# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component />

Tags: reactjs

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";

class Practice extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.color = ["red", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
  }

  renderColor = () => {
    return this.color.map((c, i) => (
      <li key={i} value={c.color}>
        {c.color}
      </li>
    ));
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderColor}</div>;
  }
}
export default Practice;
```

=======================

```
index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in div (at Practice.js:17)
    in Practice (at src/index.js:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the renderColor method, you're just passing the function, you need to call the function:

```
return <div>{this.renderColor()}</div>;
```